# Telerik RadGridView keeping selected rows when we switch page by DataPager

Tags: telerik, silverlight-5.0

If I go from one page RadGridView to the next (by DataPager) I lose the row selection from the previous page.

This is why if I come back, previously selected items will not be selected anymore.

How can I keep selected rows in RadDataGrid?

Code:

```
        <telerik:RadGridView Margin="5" Grid.Row="2"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Name="DataGrid" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ShowGroupPanel="False" 
            CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
            CanUserInsertRows="False"
            CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
            telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8"
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            ValidatesOnDataErrors="None" 
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding View}"
            IsBusy="{Binding View.IsBusy}"
            RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
            FilterOperatorsLoading="DataGrid_FilterOperatorsLoading">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:MultiSelectBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Производитель" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MakerName}" ShowDistinctFilters="False"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Номер" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Number}" ShowDistinctFilters="False"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Наименование" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" ShowDistinctFilters="False"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Товарная группа" DataMemberBinding="{Binding GroupName}" ShowDistinctFilters="False"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Вес" DataMemberBinding="{Binding WeightPhysical}" ShowDistinctFilters="False"/>
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
        <telerik:RadDataPager Height="28" Grid.Row="3"
            NumericButtonCount="20"
            Margin="5" 
            Name="DataPager" 
            Source="{Binding View}" 
            telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" 
            DisplayMode="All"
            Style="{StaticResource RadDataPagerStyle}"
            AutoEllipsisMode="None"/>
```

Comment: 1. Are you using WinForms or WebForms? 2. Can you provide your code and what you've already tried?

Comment: I am using Silverlight. Now I don't trying anything.

Comment: Uff. I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with Silverlight :/ I hope someone else will see the questions and is able to help.